# how to pass a variable to a user control to be used as selectcommand of sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, sqldatasource

I don't understand why a property `ParentScheduleItemId` in my usercontrol is always zero.  All I want to do is pass a value to my user control so that it can be used as a selectparameter of a selectcommand in a SqlDataSource.  I have the following code below, which seems to cause  `ParentScheduleItemId == 0`, but it actually prints the expected non-zero value that I passed it in the ascx file right beside the sentence `No data was returned`:

```
namespace CCApplication.Cms
{
    public partial class schedule_sub_item : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public int ParentScheduleItemId {
            get;

            set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ParentScheduleItemId", ParentScheduleItemId.ToString());
            //SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ParentScheduleItemId", "12");
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code in the ascx file

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewConferencesApplicationConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="
SELECT [ScheduleItemId],[ParentScheduleItemId],[Name],[Type],[Location],[MaximumUsers],[CompanionAllowed],[StartTime],[EndTime]
FROM [Conferences_ScheduleItem]
WHERE ParentScheduleItemId = @ParentScheduleItemId
ORDER BY StartTime;
            "
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Conferences_ScheduleItem] WHERE [ScheduleItemId] = @ScheduleItemId"
            >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>


        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ScheduleItemId" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.<% Response.Write(ParentScheduleItemId.ToString()); %></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ScheduleItemIdLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("ScheduleItemId") %>' />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                            <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

So all I want to do is do something like `<usercontrol:mylistview ParentScheduleItemId=24>` and then for 24 to be used as part of my SelectCommand.  How do I achieve this?

Note - you'll notice that I commented out the line             `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ParentScheduleItemId", "12");` .  If i uncomment it, it actually behaves as expected, and gives the number 12 to my select parameters and the sqldatasource gives me the values I want. I just don't understand why the line above it has a ParentScheduleItemId == 0.  Does this have something to do with the page load cycle?  Anyway, i just want to pass the right parentscheduleitemid to my select command.

Comment: Set breakpoints at `   set; }` and `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("ParentScheduleItemId", ParentScheduleItemId.ToString());`, see which one hits first.

Comment: i have confirmed that pageload fires before the setter function of ParentScheduleItemId.   So now I'm not sure how/when to pass a variable to my selectcommand....

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was frustrating.  I found the solution after 3 hours of banging my head against the wall.  Here's the working code:

// codebehind

```
namespace CCApplication.Cms
{

public partial class schedule_sub_item : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string _parentScheduleItemId;
    public string ParentScheduleItemId {
        get
        {
            return _parentScheduleItemId;
        }
        set
        {
            _parentScheduleItemId = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void UpdateSqlParametersEventHandler(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbParameter param = e.Command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@ParentScheduleItemId";
        param.Value = this._parentScheduleItemId;
        e.Command.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
}
}
```

//frontend code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewConferencesApplicationConnectionString %>" 
OnSelecting="UpdateSqlParametersEventHandler"
            SelectCommand="
SELECT [ScheduleItemId],[ParentScheduleItemId],[Name],[Type],[Location],[MaximumUsers],[CompanionAllowed],[StartTime],[EndTime]
FROM [Conferences_ScheduleItem]
WHERE ParentScheduleItemId = @ParentScheduleItemId
ORDER BY StartTime;
            "
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Conferences_ScheduleItem] WHERE [ScheduleItemId] = @ScheduleItemId"
            >
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ScheduleItemId" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        No data was returned.<% Response.Write(ParentScheduleItemId.ToString()); %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="ScheduleItemIdLabel" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("ScheduleItemId") %>' />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                        <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
                    <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

So basically I needed to add a OnSelecting="UpdateSqlParametersEventHandler", then add that function in the code behind to set the parameter.

The reason i was having problems before was because the page load cycle was causing the sqldatasource to run before the ParentScheduleItemId was even being set ...